# How do we get the current Authentication Mode in SharePoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a sharepoint site which has different authentication options available for users to login like Windows, Trusted SAML etc

How can i determine which is the authentication mode of the current request?

I have tried the "SPSecurity.AuthenticationMode" but its value is always forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get it via SPOriginalIssuerType Property

```
var localClaimManager = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
                if (localClaimManager != null)
                {
                    var issuerType=SPOriginalIssuers.GetIssuerType(localClaimManager.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).OriginalIssuer);
                    //Write your logic based on the issuerType received
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.claims.sporiginalissuertype?view=sharepoint-server

                }
```